# using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~7.0.0

Tags: cordova, phonegap

I used **android platform add android**  but only getting reponse as
using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@7.0.0

I am clueless how can I install android platform for my cordova app?
please find below image
[cordova add platform issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR3oP.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try install old version.

```
npm uninstall -g cordova
npm install -g cordova@6.5.0
cordova platform add android
```

this working good with :

```
node : 6.0.0
npm :  4.6.1
```